# ¿Como puedo usar los archivos tpl?

Tags: html

Buenas tardes a todos tengo un proyecto en los cuales los arhivos estan en fomrato tpl y cuando quiero editarlos en vscode me aparece asi ademas de que no me deja presivualizarlo estoy usando las plantillas de hostbill

asi me aparece [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como puedo cambiar los estilos?

Comment: Has probado a buscar en Google? He encontrado varios convertidores de tpl a html

Comment: El formato **tpl** como tal diria que no existe. **tpl** significa **template** (plantilla), y se supone que se puede usar como extensión de cualquier sistema de plantillas que quiera usarlo, sin ser necesariamente un estandar de nada.  Algunos frameworks pondran el contenido a su manera y otros de otra, cambiando el sistema de variables que tengan sin importar como sean los demás. Desde mi punto de vista no es nada más que una extensión cualquiera sin ninguna implicación directa con un formato concreto. En cada caso se ceñirá al framework o sistema de codificación que lo esté usando.

Comment: Fíjate que en el caso concreto que comentas, el archivo **tpl** es un html relleno de variables que se resuelven en tiempo de ejecución del hostbill que estás usando. Puedes editarlos cambiando su codificación a HTML dentro del VSCode para que te lo pinte un poco mejor, pero ojo con eliminar variables o cosas que parecen comentarios, pues no tienen pinta de serlo en este caso.  Dedícate simplemente a tocar el HTML que conozcas y para verlo, aunque de forma rara, lo puedes volcar en un navegador e intuir más o menos el resultado de tu edición, la cual no sabras hasta que hostbill lo procese.

Comment: ok entoces de nada me serviria seguir buscando un compilador o algo asi, porque es algo que hasta que suba al hostbill se vera el resultado final final

Comment: Exacto, pero como te decia, si te fijas, es HTML lleno de variables de hostbill y puedes abrirlo en un navegador a ver que sale y hacerte una idea de lo que son esas variables sin borrar ninguna, a menos que estes seguro de ello por las razones que tengas.  Y para que te lo pinte en el VSCode le tienes que decir que su formato es HTML y así podrá aplicarle el colorido adecuado para ese codigo y lo verás mejor cuando lo edites allí.

Comment: entiendo, gracias por la ayuda ya me siento mas tranquilo

Comment: de nada :-)  Suerte! Saludos